# Add start of the week as time-stamp

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I have a postgres table where one column transaction_time as a timestamp. I want to create a new column and assign a value to it, which displays the date-time of the starting day of the week corresponding to the values in transaction_time for every row in the table.

For eg.
For 2017-12-20 12:12:00 I want the transaction time to be displayed as 2017-12-17 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

Use [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

```
select date_trunc('week', timestamp '2017-12-20 12:12:00');
```

Comment: I'd like to do it for every row in the table.

Comment: @user8176713: `select date_trunc('week', the_timestamp_column) from your_table`

Comment: Thank you do much for the answer! But there is one more problem that needs to be addressed. From this Wednesday to the next Tuesday I want to display in a new column, this sunday's date. 
So corresponding to next Tuesday it'll display this sunday's date but for next Wednesday it should display next sunday's date. How should I do this?

Comment: @user8176713: please do not extend the scope of your question once you have an answer. [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead (you can link back to this one. If this solved your (initial) problem, you should accept the answer, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried doing that but I've been banned now.